# rails db:migrate fails '[MODEL].users' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `users`

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, devise, dbmigrate

I done lot of googling and read lot of stack overflow pages , but can't fix this issues. If any one can help with this , it will be helpful.

My app works fine still yesterday , now suddenly it starts to give error on "rake db:migrate"

I check my scheme its fine , i tried after rake db:drop / db:create / db:migrate , i checked for devise in Gem file.

My Error :

[image]

My Schema :

[image]

My Gem File :

[image]

Any help will be very use ful.

Thanks.

Error as Text :

Senthil:zenkars senthilkumar$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Table 'zenkars_development.users' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `users`

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Senthil:zenkars senthilkumar$ rake db:migrate --trace

** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)

** Invoke environment (first_time)

** Invoke disable_rails_admin_initializer (first_time)

** Execute disable_rails_admin_initializer

** Execute environment

rake aborted!

Mysql2::Error: Table 'zenkars_development.users' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `users`
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query'

Comment: Please paste the error here....as it is an image is not clear

Comment: I edited question sorry for unclear image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link out

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1273

Basically you need to remove rails_admin configuration from user model and write it as the deprecated way.

Comment: what about those of us that have the same problem, but don't use RailsAdmin?